# On wordpress.org, what is the logic behind closing support tickets permanently?

Tags: wordpress.org, support

Even moderators on wordpress.org can't reopen tickets:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-open-a-closed-for-reply-topic-as-a-moderator/

This is weird and stupid. The question for SE is:

**Has Automattic expressed the reason WHY they do this? Can you provide a link to trac or a blog post where they explain themselves?**

Comment: Automattic doesn't run .org, they don't run the support forums, they don't moderate the support forums, and they don't sponsor people to run the .org forums. Automattic runs WordPress.com the hosted WP service, they are not the WordPress open source project. I say this as someone who used to work there and saw all the internal stuff, but also the person who closed your support thread doesn't work at Automattic either. The .org support forum is ran by volunteers

Comment: Having said that, this stack is for questions about programming with WordPress. How the .org site is ran is off topic here and not in the scope of this stack. You should go back to the .org forums or go to WP Make slack if you have questions about how that site is run.

Comment: Closed as unrelated to WordPress development

Comment: Tom, if you are going to editorialize, I'd appreciate you opening a new post instead of polluting mine. The human beings that run Automattic, are the same human beings that run the .org repo. Is there a reason you would attempt to obfuscate that information?

Comment: Your ticket on the support forum was closed by someone who works for Dekode, not Automattic. This question is offtopic, this stack is for questions about programming with WordPress, it is not about the .org site and how it is ran. This is not the place to ask this question, and it was closed according to our rules and scope. If you disagree, the comments are not the place to make your case, we have a meta stack for questions about the site itself and the rules it's ran by. Remember, this is not a discussion forum

Comment: It's not a discussion forum, but you took the opportunity to editorialize your point. You know, and so do all experienced WordPress people, that who "runs" the .org is a topic of controversy. By closing this question, you're attempting specifically to insert your point of view. If all questions about the .org repo are verbotten [and they certainly aren't!]. who "runs" it according to Tom Nowell is besides the point.

Comment: This site is for asking questions about WP development, this question is not about WP development, so it was closed. I'm not going to argue about this in the comments. If you have a question about the rules or believe they were applied incorrectly, post on the meta stack https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/